# Why my C++/QT application crashes in nanosleep() on Linux x86_64?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, crash, qtwebkit

I'm running a server-side webkit renderer written in Qt/C++ under Ubuntu 12.10 on x86_64. Qt is 4.8.4 custom built as well as qtwebkit 2.3.

In about 5% of all render tasks the application crashes like that (gdb log):

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/something...done.
[New LWP 27328]
[New LWP 27825]
[New LWP 27807]
[New LWP 28981]
[New LWP 27808]
[New LWP 28387]
[New LWP 28575]
[New LWP 28837]
[New LWP 28879]
[New LWP 28891]
[New LWP 27326]
[New LWP 28420]
[New LWP 28681]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/home/something'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f793a58183d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
#0  0x00007f793a58183d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#1  0x00007f793a5816dc in __sleep (seconds=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sleep.c:138
#2  0x00007f793db80014 in ?? () from /usr/local/qt-4.8.4-git/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4
#3  0x00007f793db80309 in ?? () from /usr/local/qt-4.8.4-git/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4
#4  0x00007f793b09de9a in start_thread (arg=0x7f7934b41700) at pthread_create.c:308
#5  0x00007f793a5b5cbd in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:112
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) quit
```

How is this even possible? What can I do to mitigate this crash?

*Update:* backtrace for other threads here: http://pastie.org/5623164

Comment: what does the stack trace for the other threads look like?

Comment: I don't see anything useful there as well: http://pastie.org/5623164

Comment: you haven't posted a [`sscce`](http://sscce.org) so we can't do much to help. Have you tried running under valgrind?

Comment: Not possible to provide a test case. I'm running about 2,000 instances of this (huge) software across servers, respawning every five minutes each. I get about 2% crashes like that in random times with no apparent pattern of reproductivity. 

Sure, I tried valgrind many times on this app, but found no apparent leaks in my code.

Comment: I'm not sure I trust gdb's output here... I've seen cases where the stack trace reported doesn't have much to do with the cause of the actual crash (either because it's the stack trace of the wrong thread, or because memory got munged sufficiently that gdb got confused).  I'd try grepping the Qt source files for all calls to sleep() and putting a printf() (or whatever debug function you like) just before each one, and see if Qt is even calling sleep() or nanosleep() at all... I don't know why it would be in your application.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out, this is a false backtrace. After replacing the libQtWebKit with the same build but with debug symbols, I get a whole different backtrace which is meaningful.

tl;dr - there is no crash in nanosleep(), it's just a wrong resolution by gdb.